# Formatting CSV Schema for Biq Query API

Tags: python, csv, google-bigquery

I'm using Google Big Query's python api library and trying to upload a csv file with multiple columns. How should I format the schema? I'm getting an error that says "cannot load csv data with nested schema" using the following

```
    "schema": { 
      "fields": [ 
        {"fields": [{"name":"elevation","type":"FLOAT"}, 
                    {"name":"landcover","type":"STRING"} ],

          "type": "RECORD",
          "name": "properties", 
        },
      ],
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have one too many `fields`. Try this:

```
"schema": { 
    "fields": [
        {"name":"elevation","type":"FLOAT"}, 
        {"name":"landcover","type":"STRING"}
    ],
    ...
```

You can see an example in their docs [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery#loaddatagcs).